# centre the x axis around the peak value

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way in ggplot to centre the x axis around the peak value for t for each patient (id), rather than starting it at day 0? I have currently displayed it as below, but it is just a big mess as they all start at different times…

Many thanks, Annemarie

```
a <- ggplot(df, aes(x=day, y=t, group=id)) 
a + geom_line(aes(colour=id))

id day  t   
1   0   25   
1   1   100   
1   2   30   
1   3   20   
1   4   5  
1   5   0  
2   0   0  
2   1   0  
2   2   25  
2   3   70  
2   4   25  
2   5   10  
3   0   5  
3   1   10  
3   2   15  
3   3   15  
3   4   120  
3   5   60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind:

```
library(dplyr)

df = df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(day.centered = day - day[which.max(t)])

ggplot(df, aes(x=day.centered, y=t, group=id)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=id))
```

Note that if there is more than one `t` (for a given `id`) that has the maximum value, then this method will set the day of the first maximum to zero.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is exactly perfect! Thanks very much